# HTML content on new lines has overlapping background effect

Tags: html, css, web

Below is my problem, these are the same link and the orange background is a hover effect set in css. As you can see when the window is compressed the text of the link moves onto the next lines to fit the screen. But the background effect of each line obscures the second. I can set the display to be block, but that would stretch the background to 100% of the window, which isn't what I want when the page is not narrow.

[image]

Thanks in advance

EDIT: CODE

```
<div class="PageSection">
    <a class="LinkButton" href="">This Is My Link, There Are Many Like It But This One Is Mine</a>
</div>

.PageSection {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
.LinkButton {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 100%;

    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
.LinkButton:hover {
    background-color: #FF5A19;
}
```

EDIT:
I know I could set the line-height css property, but that gives the link ugly spacing, and I am also aiming for a square block of background colour, just not to the full width of the page.

Comment: To help, we need code... Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: no problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/dLby4LLy/

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior from the screenshot with your demo.

Comment: Also, Chris Coyier has a long article on exactly this topic: [Multi-Line Padded Text](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/)

Answer (score 0):

I think i have managed to do what you wanted, do you want it multi-lined even on full width or when page width is smaller

I have used multiple spans tags to controls the lines

```
<div class="PageSection">
    <a class="LinkButton" href=""><span>This Is My Link, </span> <span> There Are Many Like </span> <span> It But This One Is Mine </span></a>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle on what i have achieved

**I HAVE UPDATED THE FIDDLE** to your desired outcome
[See the FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsanpervaiz/3jawfat8/)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your padding is for creating that extra block effect.

try

```
.PageSection {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
.LinkButton {
    /*padding: 5px 0 5px 0;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
.LinkButton:hover {
    background-color: #FF5A19;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0px #FF5A19,-10px 0 0 0px #FF5A19;
}
```

all you need on the link is `background-clip: padding-box;` on the link and some box-shadow to cover the extra bit where padding can't reach due to inline element behaviour.

Edit: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luongatoolz/dLby4LLy/3/)